# How make access to injected ngControl from unit tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

How make access to injected ngControl from unit tests?
How resolve the error?

In component

```
constructor(
    @Self() @Optional() public ngControl: NgControl
  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ngControl.valueChanges
```

In unit test

```
beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(component);
      fixture.detectChanges();
```

When executing the test get the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works with:

```
beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(сomponent);
     (fixture.componentInstance as any).ngControl = new FormControl();
```

Answer (score 12):

I solved this by overriding

```
    beforeEach(async () => {
      const NG_CONTROL_PROVIDER = {
          provide: NgControl,
          useClass: class extends NgControl {
          control = new FormControl();
          viewToModelUpdate() {}
      },
    };

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponentName],
      imports: [FormsModule],
    })
      .overrideComponent(YourComponentName, {
        add: { providers: [NG_CONTROL_PROVIDER] },
      })
      .compileComponents();
  });
```

Comment: [You're life saver!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827771/mock-ngcontrol-in-unit-test-to-access-validators)

Comment: Oke, this works. Could you elaborate a bit on why this is working? For instance, why doesn't it work using `providers: [ provide: NgControl, useValue: NG_CONTROL_PROVIDER }`. Are there any caveats to overriding the control provider?

Comment: If you are running into this issue because of a directive that injects NgControl, you can replace `.overrideComponent` with `.overrideDirective` to resolve it's dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue and solved it using a mock object for the NgControl.

Define the mock object...

```
let formControlSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<NgControl>;
formControlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('NgControl', ['value']);
```

Provide the mock for component injection...

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        TestComponent,
        { provide: NgControl, useValue: formControlSpy }
    ]
});

injector = getTestBed();
component = injector.get(PasswordFormControlComponent);
```

Then configure the required value of the control...

```
beforeEach(() => formControlSpy.value.and.returnValue('value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the control, if you just want to resolve the error you can provide the NgControl like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        ...
        providers: [
            { provide: NgControl, useValue: new FormControl() },
        ]
        ...
    })
    .compileComponents()
}))
```