# Mock NgControl in unit-test to access validators

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm having trouble unit-testing a directive that sets validators via `NgControl`.

Here's what I'm doing inside my directive:

```js
constructor(private control: NgControl) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    const ctrl = this.control.control;
    if (ctrl) {
        // this condition never passes here when run inside the test

        ctrl.setValidators([/* my validators*/]);
    }
}
```

In my test, I tried a number of ways to inject that `NgControl`, like this one:

```js
{ provide: NgControl, useValue: new FormControl() }
```

But nothing works. Inside the test, `ctrl` within the directive is always `null`. In the meantime, normally the directive works perfectly.

I no longer know where to look. Any help is much appreciated!

---

I'm using Angular v12.02

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618154/how-make-access-to-injected-ngcontrol-from-unit-tests

Comment: Just did, using a modified version of an example there... and it worked :)

Comment: Hi Can you please share your spec file, I'm stuck in the same issue and it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618154/how-make-access-to-injected-ngcontrol-from-unit-tests), modified somewhat, I was able to get it to work...

It took adding two pieces...

```js
const NG_CONTROL_PROVIDER = {
    provide: NgControl,
    useClass: class extends NgControl {
        control = new FormControl();

        viewToModelUpdate() {
        }
    }
};
```

And plus the following `overrideDirective` piece before compilation:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ValidationConfigDirective, HostComponent]
})
    .overrideDirective(ValidationConfigDirective, {
        add: { providers: [NG_CONTROL_PROVIDER] }
    })
    .compileComponents();
```

Comment: I want to create an object of my directive class whose constructor take a private NgControl variable, can you please tell me how can i achieve that ?