# Getting 'NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!' when using custom control

Tags: html, angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I customized a radio button. It is working so far. But I noticed I have the mentioned error in my console and cannot run any tests. This is a common error but the existing solutions on SO could not help me so far.

Here is my code:

radio-button.component.hmtl:

```
<input
  type="radio"
  data-test-id="radio-button"
  [attr.id]="id"
  [attr.name]="name"
  [ngClass]="{
    'radio-button': disabled === false,
    'radio-button-without-focus': disabled === true,
    'disabled-radio': disabled === true
  }"
  [value]="value"
  [checked]="checked"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  (change)="onChange($event)"
/>
```

radio-button.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fls-radio-button',
  templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio-button.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioButtonComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class RadioButtonComponent extends RadioControlValueAccessor {
  @HostBinding('class') classes = 'fls-radio-button';

  @Input() id: string;

  @Input() name: string;

  @Input() value: SimpleFieldValue;

  @Input() label: string;

  @Input() disabled = false;

  @Input() checked = false;

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

radio-button.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [RadioButtonComponent],
  exports: [RadioButtonComponent, FormsModule],
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedI18nModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
})
export class RadioButtonModule {}
```

radio-button.component.spec.ts:

```
describe('RadioButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: RadioButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RadioButtonComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RadioButtonComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule, ...getSharedI18nTestingModules(), FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  const createComponent = () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RadioButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.label = 'Copy';
    component.disabled = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  };

  it('Should create', () => {
    createComponent();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule everywhere. Does anyone know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

under the hood `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` is asking injector for `NgControl` and is setting the control's `valueAccessor` prop to the value provided in `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`. So I suppose you need to provide `NgControl` in your test

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: You can check this question for solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618154/how-make-access-to-injected-ngcontrol-from-unit-tests